# How to run asp code, retrieved from the database

Tags: html, asp.net, controls

I have one single page in my ASP project, where upon clicking a different link, I retrieve ,from the database, the according HTML and load it. So I have some links, that are sitting in the page at all time (the part of the HTML that is not retrieved from the DB) but in some divs I get the HTML, and in there I also have links, that I'd like to run as ASP `LinkButton` controls.

This is, f.e., that always stays:

```
<div id="mainCenter">
    <asp:Literal ID="ltlContentCenter" runat="server" />
</div>
```

So in my code behind I have this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    ltlContentCenter.Text = getPageCenter("media"); //function that retrieves
    ltlContentSide.Text = getPageSide("media");    // the HTML from the database
}
```

What I have in the DB, corresponding, is:

```
<div class="onCenterSmall">
    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton10" Text="test" CommandArgument="test" OnCommand="loadPage_Command"
                runat="server" />
</div>
<div class="onCenterSmall"></div>
<div class="onCenterSmall"></div>
```

That chunk of HTML just gets put in between the `<div id="mainCenter"><!-- in here --></div>` on the page.
And as you can see by yourself I get the result as string. For the HTML code that's fine, but for the `<asp:LinkButton...` that doesn't quite work. Any suggestions how I can do all the work in the same way (or at least to preserve the logic) but to get the `LinkButton control` working ?

Answer (score 1):

I have my doubts with the approach that you're taking (why are you storing fragments of ASP.NET markup in your database?) but if you must, I think `Page.ParseControl` is your friend. See [MSDN: TemplateControl.ParseControl Method (String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kz3ffe28.aspx).

You can use `Page.ParseControl` to build a `Control` out of the input string, which you can then append to the `Controls` collection of any control (such as a [`PlaceHolder` control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.placeholder.aspx)).

Comment: This is kind of a solution but I still need to put this control (link) in between a `div` that I get from the database. And I cannot write `<asp:PlaceHolder ID="myPlaceHolder" runat="server" />` in the HTML which is in the DB, because it will still get out as a String and not work. I can only write it in the code of the page that always stays there, thus not giving me the desired result. By this I am still back to the old problem.

Comment: The ````asp:PlaceHolder```` control has to be on the page you're adding the content from the database to, it doesn't have to be in your content.

Comment: Scenario: `<div id="mediaWindow">
            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="myPlaceHolder" runat="server" />
            <asp:Literal ID="ltlContentCenter" runat="server" />
        </div>`. Here the `placeholder` adds the control and then the rest of the content is added. But in the content, there are other child divs that are under the parent "mediaWindow" and I need the control in one of them child divs. So basically I have to show (with the placeholder) where to put the control, which doesn't help me in this case.

Comment: In this case you should use the placeholder as a container to which you will add the content you retrieve from the database. You should drop the ````ltlContentCenter```` literal altogether as that control does not allow you to add parsed controls.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you say that I gotta load into the `PlaceHolder` both the html (the content) and the other controls? 
But then I couldn't find how to add the content into the `placeholder`. As, i.e., I was using `ltlContent.Text = ...thecontent` as string. And then have the code as follows: `myPlaceHolder.addTheContent; myPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(control)... `

Comment: In your original code you used a ````Literal```` to put your content in. Since the Literal doesn't allow putting in child controls in the way you want to, you'll have to use a different control: the ````PlaceHolder````. Using ````Page.ParseControl(thecontent)````, you will get a ````Control```` object which you can in turn add as a child control to the ````Placeholder```` by using ````myPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(output_from_Page_ParseControl)````

Comment: Okey, now I am moving somewhere. But the design of the page ruins as the children divs in the left parent div are ok, but the children divs of the right parent go under (as if they don't belong to it). I know this is css/html related problem already, but if I load the HTML code without using this latest technique, we came to, everything looks fine. So maybe you know what the problem is ? (I looked everywhere else in the HTML code and there is no element, who will make them children divs to move).

Comment: If that happens that means that your mark-up is incorrect. Perhaps you're forgetting to close a ````<div>```` or you closed one too much.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not going to answer your question, but just a few thoughts:

1. Why would you need to use a link button? Why not just use a standard html anchor tag
2. If it is because you need to execute some code how do you plan to deal with the code behind? Are you going to assume all html stored inside the DB inherits from the same class.

It just has to be said that this sounds like a really terrible idea though. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: The whole idea of getting the HTML from the DB and so on is TERRIBLE, I know... but that is my boss' request. Can't argue with that.
I need a LinkButton control because I have only 1 single page, which I update (load) with corresponding HTML code, thus I cannot use `<a>` tags to navigate through different pages, but instead use the control to know when to load the next corresponding HTML. :)